# Error playing video when using OpenCV C++ on a Visual Studio platform

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to get it running, but it didn't do anything, didn't show up errors and automatically terminated the program.

```
#include"opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include"opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include"opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv)
{
    cvNamedWindow("Example2", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    CvCapture* capture = cvCreateFileCapture("C:/Users/Nam/Pictures/YALQ6371.MP4");
    IplImage* frame;
    while (1){
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (!frame) break;
        cvShowImage("Example2", frame);
        char c = cvWaitKey(33);
        if (c == 27) break;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example2");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code is written in c-api. C-api is deprecated which version opencv are u using?

Comment: Opencv 3.0.0 and visual studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

Try using `imshow` instead of `cvShowImage`, but don't forget to add `using namespace cv;` at the beginning.

Comment: I followed your instructions but it came up with error: Error 1 error C2665: 'cv :: imshow': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types ...

Comment: Error: IntelliSense: no instance of overloaded function "imshow" matches the argument list argument types are: (const char [9], IplImage *)

Comment: You should define `frame` as `Mat` not `IplImage*`.